# Overview of amdgpu clock and temperature

Tags: linux, gpu, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I remember there was some sysfs/procfs (or maybe debugfs?) file that provided formatted textual overview of GPU temperature, clock and some more information. I can't remember path to the file and I also can't find it. What is the path?

The contents of the file were in `Name of parameter: value Unit` format and it included nearly all interesting information – temp, core&mem frequencies, usage percentage, and also some other things.

I was using Linux 5.x with amdgpu driver.

Comment: Something like [radeontop](https://github.com/clbr/radeontop)

Answer (score 1):

From https://dri.freedesktop.org/docs/drm/gpu/amdgpu.html

- power_dpm_state
- power_dpm_force_performance_level
- pp_table
- pp_od_clk_voltage
- pp_dpm_* : pp_dpm_sclk, pp_dpm_mclk, pp_dpm_socclk, pp_dpm_fclk, pp_dpm_dcefclk and pp_dpm_pcie
- pp_power_profile_mode
- gpu_busy_percent/mem_busy_percent
- gpu_metrics: *These data include temperature, frequency, engines utilization, power consume, throttler status, fan speed and cpu core statistics( available for APU only)*

All found in `/sys/class/drm/card0/device/` (or card1, card2, etc).

Comment: That is really weird. I remember there was some file in sysfs (or procfs or debugfs) that provided all information in quite well-formatted text. `gpu_metrics` sounds like that, but I do not have APU. Maybe I should try out older kernels.